# How resume facebook login profile data in android

Tags: android, facebook-login, onresume, onstart

I have my app when i Log with Facebook. Everything works in the first time when i log, but when for example i press the back button and next return in the app i have lose all facebook data(profile name, id,....) and i don't know how i recover these. There is some methods (onStart-onClose as in google login) for resume this data? when i return in my app the system print me only the AccessTokenTracker and AccessToken

```
accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken,AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                // Set the access token using
                // currentAccessToken when it's loaded or set.
                System.out.println("Questo è accesso token "+currentAccessToken);
                System.out.println("Questo è accesso OLDtoken "+oldAccessToken);
            }
        };
        // If the access token is available already assign it.
        accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
```

How could i use these values to take back user data? Or are there other ways for get this information?

Thank you!

Comment: save all data in local in your app

Comment: just relog with the getCurretAccessToken.